# Flex layout broken in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm completely lost, I read so much things and I still couldn't figure it out how to fix this layout working in IE11 :(

**HTML**

```
<div class="site">
  <header>
    <div class="wrap">
      Header
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="site-content">
    <div class="wrap">
      <aside>
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 1</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <article>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="wrap">Footer</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

article {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

footer {
  background: #eee;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoZJWj

It's working in every browsers but IE11 makes me crazy.
Thanks in advance

Comment: display: flex; has partial support in IE11, check here http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex

Comment: There are ways to solve it though, look at the known issues list there.

Comment: List where please ?

Comment: You can do something like: https://jsfiddle.net/urqtxgpb/1/, set parent and child height to 100% (will work with vh, i think)... min-height is for some reason ignored by ie11 (it seems)

Comment: And here is explanation:https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items